# Windows-1251 to UTF-8 codes

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I have code of character in Windows-1251 code table.
How i can get code of this character in UTF-8 code table?

For example i have character 'А' with coded in Windows-1251 equals 192, appropriate utf-8 code equals 1040

How i can to initialize Character or char in Java with code 192 from Windows-1251 code table?

char c = (char)192; //how to specify the encoding ?

Comment: All ASCII characters, including `A` are the same in Window-1251, ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8. Its the characters > 127 which are different.

Comment: Do you have the code points, the characters, a string? Some more information would be helpful. - If it's a string you could just define CP-1251 encoding when reading it from a stream/file and UTF-8 encoding when writing it to a stream/file.

Comment: My original task is to check if character valid (can be used in string). The list of valid characters code i have in Windows-1251 code table. Valid Characters can be set as range from-to (32-235). I want to compare given character with range, but given character is in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To convert a byte[] encoding in one character encoding to another you can do

```
public static byte[] convertEncoding(byte[] bytes, String from, String to) {
    return new String(bytes, from).getBytes(to);
}
```

Comment: But if you convert output `byte[]` to string you'll get wrong string