# Russian character not showing well in java but is ok in php?

Tags: java, php

We have a web application where the can insert russian character and in the mysql db it looks like this Ð”Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð²ÐºÐ° Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð°. But when is viewed on the web is shows correctly in the russian character form. But when we do it in java application it showing up in this format Ð”Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð²ÐºÐ° Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð°? Any help?

Part of the java codes are below.

```
Statement stmt1 = null;
                         //System.out.println("\n\nSELECT selectOTACommand : "+selectOTACommand);
                         String select1 = "Select locName from tblLoc where locID=2280"
                         ResultSet rs1= stmt1.executeQuery(select1);
                         while(rs1.next()) 
                         {
                            System.out.println("Loc Name : "+rs1.getString("locName"));

                         }      

                          try{
                            if ( rs1 != null ){
                              rs1.close();
                            }
                            else{
                                System.out.println("MyError:rs1 is null in finally close");
                            }
                            if ( stmt1 != null ){
                              stmt1.close();
                            }
                            else{
                                System.out.println("MyError:stmt1 is null in finally close");
                            }
                          }
                          catch(SQLException ex){
                                System.out.println("MyError:SQLException has been caught for stmt1 close");
                                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                          }
```

Comment: is Java rendering using UTF-8? Western Unicode? Could be the character set Java is using.

Comment: *"Any help?"* - Just properly specify the encoding and this is a no-brainer. What is your question?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I have put the chunk of the java codes. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you see this output (console/JSP)?

Comment: I see it in console it self as this is a java application running as daemon.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set on three places the encoding that is used, so that it will be ok and the way it should be.

1. php
2. mysql database and table
3. the link that php uses to communicate with mysql (this is what most ppl miss) you have two options here. phps' `mysql_set_charset()` ->   [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) or doing itwith two queries `SET NAMES 'charset_name'` + `SET CHARACTER SET charset_name`

Comment: now for the php it works fine as I can insert n view it well. The problem is in java now.

Comment: ...and that's (most,most likely) because your php application does it wrong but you don't notice it because it does it wrong both on the input and the output way and two wrongs -in this case- cancle each other out ;-)

Comment: well java isn't my specialty, but if java runs by default in utf8 you can try the same approach as in step 3 :), but from javas' end.

Comment: @all so what should I do it right via php is it then it should work well in java is it?

Comment: ok i am confused, is php+mysql working or not?do you have the text stored correctly in mysql?

Comment: Yes I have the text stored into mysql via php. But in mysql this is how it looks like Ð”Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð²ÐºÐ° Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð° but when I view back in php it looks the correct characters ?

Comment: when php shows it right it doesn't mean that it's stored right.do you have smth like phpmyadmin?to check how and what exactly is stored in the database?

Comment: @nikola this is how it is stored in the db via the phpmyadmin Ð”Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð²ÐºÐ° Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð°?

Comment: ok so there is a problem from the php end. here is what you need to to do : 1. open phpmyadmin and check the charset and collation of the database and table you are using. if both are utf8 ok here is no problem. next, open the *.php file and check to see what charset its set to unicode (you can use notepad++ and look don on the right corner). if its ok, then open the file where you connect to the database, right after connect execute step 3, before executing anything else to the database. Then make an insert (new insert), and check the row in the database via phpmyadmin, it should read fine

Comment: Ok the tables side I get this Statements Value
Format Compact
Collation latin1_swedish_ci. How check on the .php if I dont have notepad++ ?

Comment: well it shouldn't be latin_swedish_ci it should be either utf8_unicode_ci or utf8_general_ci. well i don't know what code editor you are using, if you don't have notepad++ just download it, it's free.

Comment: ok I will do that what else next I should do it?

Comment: Ok I have checked via notepad++ it shows as Ansi

Comment: you have to convert it to unicode.and then go to thr place where the script connects with the databse, and run step 3 from my initial post

Comment: @nikola there are few different unicode options. So what is best option? So the default mysql is latin swedish ci right? So I should also convert those with latin sweidsh ci right? The step is there any other option for it e.g. in the config file.

Comment: sorry for not writing, was out of town, no no, everything should be utf8, and unicode for the files.

Answer (score 1):

[That application](http://2cyr.com/decode/) says that it is windows-1251 encoding.
You should probably [convert it to UTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613957/windows-1251-to-utf-8-codes).

Comment: So now I must covert to utf in java is it?

Comment: It is one way. I like solution with mysql_set_charset() more.

Comment: can I set it in my config file the mysql_set_charset()?;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, as Nikola said above, SET NAMES 'utf8' would solve your problem. You have to say MySQL what character set encoding your client is gonna use to send SQL statements and in what character set encoding it wants to receive the result. SET NAMES affects all these settings.

Comment: @gustave I have the config file which I call in all my application.so can I add here n what to add exactly<?php
error_reporting(0);
define('dbHost', 'localhost:3306');
define('dbUser', 'user1');
define('dbPassword', '*****');
define('dbDatabase', 'tbn');

?>

Answer (score 0):

Please first have a read of [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

After that let's take a look at your php script and how it interacts with the other components involved.

Your PHP script receives input from the client/browser, which apparently is utf-8 encoded. I.e. if the clients sends the character Д it sends the two bytes 0xD0 and 0x94.
If you take those two bytes and interpret/display them as e.g. iso-8859-1 encoded you get two characters: Ð” (just like in your question text).
Your PHP script takes those two bytes and passes them to MySQL. MySQL now has to parse/interpret those bytes, too. There are quite some encoding/charset-related settings involved in this but let's reduce it to: there's a charset associated with the connection between php and mysql and there's a charset for storing the data "within" the MySQL server. (For more information have a read of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html).
It looks like the connection charset in your case is something like iso-8859-1. I.e. the MySQL server interprets 0xD0,0x94 *not* as `Д` but as `Ð”` - two characters.
When your php script gets the data back from the MySQL server the server sends two characters, `Ð` and `”`. Since the connection charset php<->mysql still is iso-8859-1 the MySQL server encodes those two characters again as 0xD0 and 0x94.
PHP takes those two bytes (doesn't have a clue about utf-8 but that doesn't matter in this case) and sends it back to the client.
The client now has to interpret those two bytes. In your case ("when is viewed on the web") the client most likely fetches the information about the encoding from either a header in the http response or from an equivalent parameter within your html document. And this parameter seems to be "the stream is utf-8" encoded. Therefore the two bytes 0xD0,0x94 are displayed as `Д` again. So from the client/webbrowser's point of view everything is fine, php doesn't care about the mistake and neither does MySQL in this case. (There are problems that can arise "within" your php script and "within" the MySQL server...)

So, everything looks fine here - but ...that's mostly because php doesn't care. Java on the other hand usually does.
I.e. when the MySQL server sends the two "characters" `Ð` and `”` they will be handled as two separate characters in the java application. And when those two characters are send to the client that will be encoded in a way that the client will interpret them as two seperate characters as well and so on and on. (At least usually there a lot more automagically handled by default.)
Same with the frontend you've used to peek into the MySQl database. It apparently handled the encoding correctly and therfore displayed `Ð”Ð¾‚Ð°Ð²ÐºÐ° Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð°`instead of `Дотавка груза`.

---

- Make sure your database/table column encoding can handle the characters you have to store; utf-8 can do it. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html
- Make sure your php script sets the connection encoding to utf-8 since that's what the script seems to receive from the client anyway, no need to convert it to another charset first. How to do that depends on the API youre using to connect to the MySQL server:

[mysql](http://docs.php.net/mysql) (mysql_connect): this module is deprecated, think about using another module like mysqli or pdo. The correct way to set the connection charset would be

```
mysql_set_charset('utf-8', $mysql);
```

That function is php>=5.2.3 but any other method like `SET NAMES` leaves the client library in the dark about the connection charset so e.g. mysql_real_escape() may not work correctly. see http://docs.php.net/mysql_set_charset

[mysqli](http://docs.php.net/mysqli) ( new MySQLi(), mysqli_connect ) : see http://docs.php.net/mysqli.set-charset.php

[pdo](http://docs.php.net/pdo) ( new PDO('mysql:...') ):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=HOSTNAME;port=3306;dbname=DATABASENAME;charset=utf8');
```

PHP >= 5.3.6, see http://docs.php.net/ref.pdo-mysql.connection

Comment: yes u are right now I am first changing on the db part because all was latin as the default i did notchange any thing till now i am in this problem. The mysql_set_chraset can I set in a config file to be called each time?

Comment: There are patches for the mysql module that allow you to define a default charset in the php.ini/.htdocs et al. But as long as your calls to mysql_connect() aren't shattered all over the scripts it's probably better to explicitly set the charset within the script.

Comment: I have quite a number of php scripts writing to the db. So what is your best resolution? Must I also change the db collation ?